# generate dynamic id using jquery in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is a part of my .cshtml code:

```
<div class="mclass">
    <div class="MHeader">@s.Name</div>
    @foreach (var sc in @s.items)
        {
        <div class="itemclass" id="{'Item_'+@sc.itemId.ToString()}">@sc.itemId</div>
        }
</div>
```

I want to generate dynamic id for `itemclass` objects with this furmula: id = 'Item_'+ Id (Id of item).

I used above method but not answer correctly.

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? That's server-side MVC code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="itemclass" id="Item_@sc.itemId.ToString()">@sc.itemId</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
public static class MyCounter {

   private static int _uniqueID = 0;

   public static int GetCounter(){
      _uniqueID ++;
      return _uniqueID ;
    }
 }
```

and then in your cshtml file:

```
<div class="itemclass" id="{'Item_'+@GetCounter()}">@sc.itemId</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `foreach` to a `for`, you can use the counter:

```
<div class="mclass">
    <div class="MHeader">@s.Name</div>
    @for(var i = 0; i < s.items.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="itemclass" id="Item_@(i+1)">
                @s.items[i].itemId
            </div>
        }
</div>
```

The above assumes a 1 based counter on the id.

If you want to bind the collection i.e. send it back to the server you will need to understand how the model binding works.

[**Model Binding To A List Article**](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)